# É aceitável continuar uma frase usando uma citação em outra língua?

Tags: tradução-inglês, estrangeirismos, uso-mais-comum

Por exemplo:

> Estudaremos sobre colisões no contexto de funções homomórficas porque
>   o problema da convolução de polinômios "provides an estimate of the
>   difficulty of finding collision for an arbitrary homomorphic function"
>   (Author, 1980).

Alguma sugestão sobre como fazer essa citação de forma fluída no texto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das coisas mais importantes em uma redação é o diálogo com o leitor. Se o seu leitor não souber inglês, não será possível estabelecer uma boa conexão. O ideal é traduzir. E segundo a normal técnica NBR 10520, é necessário acrescentar "tradução nossa".

> Estudaremos sobre colisões no contexto de funções homomórficas porque o problema da convolução de polinômios "fornece uma estimativa da dificuldade de encontrar colisão para uma função homomórfica arbitrária" (Author, 1980, tradução nossa).